# Set up cron job every minute CPANEL

Tags: cron, cron-task

I tried to set up the cron job any minute, I tried 3 different commands.

Any of them is not working.
Below is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run cron job every minute

The syntax is:

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/script > output
```

Comment: I need it to link.

Comment: Do you have anything in your output file?

Comment: Yes its not the real output file I create this file to insert data for debugging every cron task.

Comment: Did you check the permission of your scripts? If you dont have the permission try this and rerun your job "chmod 777 yourscript"